# Running an executable with parameters in C++ and get the return value;

Tags: c++, parameters, executable, return-value

How do you run an executable with parameters passed on it from a C++ program and how do you get the return value from it?

Something like this: 
c:\myprogram.exe -v

Answer (score 15):

Portable way:

```
 int retCode = system("prog.exe arg1 arg2 arg3");
```

With embedded quotes/spaces:

```
 int retCode = system("prog.exe \"arg 1\" arg2 arg3");
```

Comment: how do you handle parameters with spaces in them? (e.g. "arg 1", "arg   2")

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, if you want a bit more control over the process, you can use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) to spawn the process, [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28VS.85%29.aspx) to wait for it to exit, and [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the return code.

This technique allows you to control the child process's input and output, its environment, and a few other bits and pieces about how it runs.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**
    How do you run an executable with parameters passed on it from a C++ program?
**Solution**
    Use `ShellExecuteEx` and `SHELLEXECUTEINFO`

**Issue**
    How do you get the return value from it?
**Solution**
    Use `GetExitCodeProcess` and `exitCode`

**Essential things to know**
    If you want to wait until process ,which is handling by external exe, is finished then need to use `WaitForSingleObject`

```
bool ClassName::ExecuteExternalExeFileNGetReturnValue(Parameter ...)
{
    DWORD exitCode = 0;
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
    ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.lpVerb = _T("open");
    ShExecInfo.lpFile = _T("XXX.exe");        
    ShExecInfo.lpParameters = strParameter.c_str();   
    ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = strEXEPath.c_str();
    ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL; 
    ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);

    if(WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE) == 0){             
        GetExitCodeProcess(ShExecInfo.hProcess, &exitCode);
        if(exitCode != 0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Reference to know more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10896836/900284)