# how to get return value of an exe called by ShellExecute

Tags: c++, c, api, winapi, shellexecute

How to get the return value of an exe which is called by shellexecute function.

```
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, TEXT ( ".\\dpinstx86.exe" ), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

In the above example I want the return value of "dpinstx86.exe".

Comment: I think what you mean by "return value" is the output from CMD, which this question addresses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469152/using-shellexecuteex-and-capturing-standard-in-out-err.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead to get the process handle, and [`GetExitCodeProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the exit code.

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = "c:\\MyProgram.exe";        
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "";   
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL; 
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
```

Comment: Don't forget to *wait* on the handle.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1842/A-newbie-s-elementary-guide-to-spawning-processes ...and call GetExitCodeProcess() with the hProcess member of SHELLEXECUTEINFO.

Comment: Dear Kol, Does the GetExitProcess returns the error code of the exe I'm calling in "ShellExecuteEx"?? i.e., does "lpExitCode" the second parameter of "GetExitProcess" contains the return value of "dpinst.exe" as per my example...and do I want to wait for the shellexecuteEx to complete?

Comment: @Hans - for clarification, *wait* meaning `WaitForSingleObject()`, I hope (new to this so please correct me if I'm wrong...)

Comment: You also leak the handle. Close it after you've waited on it. You also fail to check for errors. CreateProcess is a much better choice.